# Golang package imports - cannot find package

Tags: go

This is my first time asking a question here, anyway, I am wondering why it says it can't find the package, even though `github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion/conv` is inside the `$GOPATH`

```
[johndoe@johndoe temperature]$ go run main.go
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion/conv" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion/conv (from $GOROOT)
    /home/johndoe/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion/conv (from $GOPATH)
```

more details:

```
[johndoe@johndoe conversion]$ pwd
/home/johndoe/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion

[johndoe@johndoe conversion]$ ls
conv.go
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistaking packages and file. In go (contrary to say… python), a package is represented by a directory, and files in this directory are nothing more than code. So you should import the `github.com/JohnDoe/temperature/conversion` package.

Comment: Unless the file actually has `package conv` (and you want it to stay that way), in which case you have to move it down into a directory named `conv`.

Comment: Hi Elwinar! Thanks for answering this question. You're right, I've tried it and it works! Thanks! Will mark your answer as the correct one, in a bit...